# My HP laptop is over-heating after installing Ubuntu

Tags: power-management

I bought a new laptop a week ago (HP Pavillion 15-ab523tx) and I dual boot it with Ubuntu 16.04 along with preinstalled Windows 10.

While running Ubuntu my laptop gets extremely hot.I read about it on forums and have tried installing Nvidia Prime and enabling Intel graphics instead of my dedicated Nvidia 940m graphics card.

Though the heat has reduced little bit, it's still heating a lot. It doesn't heat even a little bit when I run Windows.

Now I want to know:

1. Is there any other solution to prevent this overheating?
2. What if I want to run my laptop on Ubuntu with Nvidia enabled. Is there any way to stop overheating in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Install `tlp` or `laptop-mode-tools` but not both.